# Triggering mouseenter several times on changing height for block

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is problem with absolute positioned blocks - when I use $('.my-block').mouseenter() and change height in its handler - mouseenter triggers as many as it crosses other such blocks.

for example some thing like this:

```
.items{position:relative;}
.item{position:absolute;}
```

```
<div class="items">
  <div class="item item1" style="top:0; z-index:1"></div>
  <div class="item item2" style="top:50; z-index:2"></div>
  <div class="item item3" style="top:100; z-index:3"></div>
  <div class="item item4" style="top:150; z-index:4"></div>
</div>
```

```
$('item').hover(function(event){
console.log("mouseenter triggered");

$(this).stop().animate({
height:400px; // it should to grow up direction
},{
step=function(now, fx){
 //changing previous items position by some magic with fx.pos and some logic
}
});

event.stopPropagation();
},function(){/*...*/})

or 

$('item').mouseenter(function(){
console.log("mouseenter triggered");
event.stopPropagation();
});
```

so when i make mouse enter on item3 in browser in log i see the string "mouseenter triggered" twice and if item4 thrice! What can I do here for preventing this?

Comment: I use just one of this methods - I just tried to watch if there any difference in using them. So it is just example.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('item').mouseenter(function(event){
console.log("mouseenter triggered");
event.stopPropagation();
});
```

you are not passing the event to the function ...